# Short story about a genetic engineer who created a retrovirus that fixed genetic diseases

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read a short story about a genetic engineer that created a retrovirus that fixed genetic diseases as well as a few other things. He also modified it to change himself to female.  There were other plot points as well.  A good story. This was in the '80s that I read the story.

This was pre Internet so I must have pulled it from one of the bulletin boards.  Compuserv?

Would any of you know who wrote it or the title?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Even though you read it online, do you think it would have been a published story that was copied over, or was an amateur story?

Comment: I think it was an amateur story.  Hadn't thought of that before.  Good question.